# pass array from module to render in template

Tags: 7, theming

I have a module name mysite.module in that module I have function named mysite_preprocess_panels_pane. That has an array and I would like to render this array inn panel.tpl.php. My code does not work. Any suggestion please, Thanks.

```
function mysite_preprocess_panels_pane(&$variables) {  
 $ar = array('arg1'=> 'car', 'arg2'=> 'truck');
}

<div class="pane-content">
<div class="panel-panel panel-col-first"> <?php print  $ar['arg1']></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the array into the variables. like.

```
function mysite_preprocess_panels_pane(&$variables) {  
 $variables['ar'] = array('arg1'=> 'car', 'arg2'=> 'truck');
}
```

Comment: Thank Leopathu, but I this error, Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children() (line 6433 of C:\xampp\htdocs\expressposmm\includes\common.inc).
Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line 5898 of C:\xampp\htdocs\expressposmm\includes\common.inc).

Comment: You can only `render()` a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760) - rendering a non-render array will produce errors

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code.

```
function mysite_theme() {
  return array(
    'panel' => array(
      'render element'=>'element', 
      'template'=>'panel', 
      'variables'=>array( 'dataar'=>NULL ), 
    )); 
}

function mysite_preprocess_panels_pane(&$variables) {  
 $ar = array('arg1'=> 'car', 'arg2'=> 'truck');
 return theme('panel',array("dataar"=>$ar));
}

// The array will be accessed in the panel.tpl.php with $dataar variable
```

Please clear cache to reflect the changes from **admin/config/development** path

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: Thanks, But i got this error when I print datarr like this <div class="panel-panel panel-col-first">a <?php print $dataar['arg1'];?> </div>.
Notice: Undefined variable: dataar in include() (line 42 of C:\xampp\htdocs\expressposmm\sites\all\modules\panels-7.x-3.0\panels\templates\panels-pane.tpl.php).